# Properly setting up path variables for root.php

Tags: php, localhost, relative-path

I just posted a similar question, but deleted it because I realized I was working with an old file...doh!

I am just trying to get my XAMPP setup working for me.

I have a live site that navigates to a login page at `http://www.monkeycalendar.com/arvindkt/login.php`

That login page includes a root.php file that is found at `http://www.monkeycalendar.com/arvindkt/root.php`

Live site works great.

My localhost is set up so my sites are a folder in localhost:

IE: http://www.example.com = localhost/example.com

I'm having problems figuring out how to make my root folder point to the right directory.  Any help would be much appreciated:

root.php:

# local settings 
 define("SITE_ROOT"      ,  $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/arvindkt");
 define("SITE_URL"      ,  "http://localhost/monkeycalendar.com");
 define('DB_HOST', "localhost");
 define('DB_USER', "root");
 define('DB_PASS', "");
 define('DB_NAME', "dev.monkeycalendar");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `root.php` resides in the site root, how about

```
define("SITE_ROOT"      ,  dirname(__FILE__));
```

Comment: I *think* that worked.  It got me to the next line and got me to an error with the db (which I haven't set up yet).  So I tentatively thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
dirname(__FILE__)
```